# Details of SSL communication

Tags: ssl, ssh

I have been trying to find out exactly how SSL works, and have found descriptions of the packet sequence that starts the conversation, but not how requests are processed.  Here is a link to an example showing the initial handshake:

https://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Networking/SSL.pdf

Once communication is established, both sides are sharing a private session key which is updated every so often.  I would like to know details on:

1. I assume that an attacker cannot just replicate an observed packet and execute it multiple times?  This is a so-called replay attack.
2. How is encryption done using AES-256?  If both sides simply applied the algorithm, then a replay attack would work.  So I assume there is some kind of chaining so that each packet uses different encryption.
3. The session key switches every interval (like once every 30 or 60 minutes. How does this exchange work?  What messages are exchanged, and what happens if a method is sent before the exchange that arrives after the switch?

   4. The underlying mechanism most recently is TLS 1.2.  Is this the same for SSL and SSH, or are the two protocols different?

An explanation is always good but a link to relevant documentation would also be extremely helpful.  If these interlocking parts are too much, I can split out into a separate question, but there is a lot of overlapping information in the above sections.

Comment: The relevant document for TLS is RFC 2246 and successors. SSH is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that an attacker cannot just replicate an observed packet and execute it multiple times? This is a so-called replay attack.

Correct. TLS is immune from replay attacks.

> How is encryption done using AES-256? If both sides simply applied the algorithm, then a replay attack would work. So I assume there is some kind of chaining so that each packet uses different encryption.

There is chaining, and sequence numbers, and also a MAC for each message.

> The session key switches every interval (like once every 30 or 60 minutes. How does this exchange work? What messages are exchanged

Another `ClientHello` with the same sessionID, and an 'abbreviated handshake' after that, that changes the session key. Details in RFC 2246.

> and what happens if a method is sent before the exchange that arrives after the switch?

The switch is by mutual agreement, and any message that arrives before the same sender's `ChangeCipherSpec` message is decrypted under the old parameters.

> The underlying mechanism most recently is TLS 1.2. Is this the same for SSL and SSH, or are the two protocols different?

They are different.